# Color 3D Surface Based on Categories that passes through scatter points

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, 3d, plotly

I have the data in the following format:

### X,Y,Z,Category

I used plotly to generate a scatter plot and then a fit a Curve through the scatter points using the following code.

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x=np.asarray([3,5,9,3,3,7,6,9,1,9]);
y=np.asarray([4,3,3,10,8,2,4,10,9,3]);
z=np.asarray([1,2,4,10,1,7,10,3,1,7]);
# x = np.random.random(100)

xi=np.linspace(min(x), max(x),50)
#print xi
yi=np.linspace(min(y),max(y),50)


X,Y= np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
Z = np.nan_to_num(griddata((x,y), z, (X, Y), method='cubic'))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False,alpha=0.4)
plt.show()
```

What i am looking to do is to color the plot according to categories something like this : 
[image]
Where red represents the category 1 and Blue represents category 2.
So inorder to get something like this I need to generate a 2D Array and then use a colormap/colorscale to color the categories accordingly.

The above output have been created using **XLSTAT** where it took category as the 4th col  as the category.

Can someone explain me how do i generate the Z data which will help me color the categories differently?

I have tried to something like dividing the 2D matrix into halves 0's and half 1's and got output something like this.

[image]

Considering the following sample data :

```
x   y   z   Category
3   4   1   Cat 1
5   3   2   cat2
9   3   4   cat2
3   10  10  cat3
3   8   1   cat3
7   2   7   cat2
6   4   10  Cat 1
9   10  3   Cat 4
1   9   1   Cat 1
9   3   7   cat2
```

**I need to generate 2D Data that will represent the surface color and color the different categories with custom color**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as [`griddata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) can be used to interpolate the 1D `z` array to a 2D grid, you can use `griddata` to interpolate a 1D `color` array to the same 2D grid:

```
color = [colormap[cat] for cat in category]
C = np.nan_to_num(griddata((x, y), color, (X, Y), method='cubic'))
```

Then you can use the colormap `cm.coolwarm` to map values in `C` to RGBA `facecolors`:

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cmap,
                linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha=0.4, facecolors=cmap(C))
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

x = np.asarray([3, 5, 9, 3, 3, 7, 6, 9, 1, 9])
y = np.asarray([4, 3, 3, 10, 8, 2, 4, 10, 9, 3])
z = np.asarray([1, 2, 4, 10, 1, 7, 10, 3, 1, 7])
category = np.array(['Cat 1', 'cat2', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat3',
                     'cat2', 'Cat 1', 'Cat 4', 'Cat 1', 'cat2'])
# coolwarm: 0 --> blue, 1 --> red
# want: 'Cat 1' --> blue, 'cat2' --> red, 'cat3' --> ?, 'Cat 4' --> ?
colormap = {'Cat 1': 0, 'cat2': 1, 'cat3': 0.333, 'Cat 4': 0.666}
color = np.array([colormap[cat] for cat in category])

xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 50)
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
Z = np.nan_to_num(interpolate.griddata((x, y), z, (X, Y), method='cubic'))
C = interpolate.griddata((x, y), color, (X, Y), method='cubic')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cmap = cm.coolwarm
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=color, cmap=cmap)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cmap,
                linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha=0.4, facecolors=cmap(C))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I used the following code to specify categories. I had seven categories , cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#638b11', '#ffc125', '#00cdcd','#4776db','#8b4789','#d3d3d3','#000000'])

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the results provided by XLSTAT though

Comment: The XLSTAT result has a "finger" of red poking into the lake of blue. And there is a "river" of blue running into the lower right corner. I don't see data points which support these features. Do you understand what XLSTAT is doing? (I don't).

Comment: No. Cant understand what they use.